# iOS images galleriers

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, uiimage, gallery

I'd like to develop an app to visualize galleries and I really like the Flickr official app or Instabam app style.

Basically, something like this (instabam app)
[image]
my idea was to use a scrollview with buttons to easily handle touch event.
Is this a good approach?
Are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using an open source library such as [AQGridView](https://github.com/pjay/AQGridView)?

Comment: it's the kind of things I was searching!! I'll try it, thank you!